# vb6 run time error 13

Tags: sql-server, vb6, runtime-error

i am using sql server for database.
In my coding when am inserting integer value into table am getting type mismatch error.
my code as

```
set rst1=cnn1.execute("select distinct(tagid) from pgevent")
```

it returns some values
when am trying to insert into another table am getting error

```
cnn1.execute("insert into tags values("+cint(rst1.fields(0).value)+")")
```

now am geting error 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are appending a numeric value to a string.

Here are the alternatives

```
cnn1.execute("insert into tags values(" & cint(rst1.fields(0).value) & ")")
```

OR

```
cnn1.execute("insert into tags values("+ rst1.fields(0).value +")")
```

Use `&` when you want something to appear as part of the string.